# how to reinstall a python environment offline?

Tags: python, pip, conda

I have server without Internet connection. I would to copy the current python environment  from another machine (installed by pip and conda) to this server by disk. That is I need to know which packages are installed, download these package and reinstall these package in the server. Is there any way to manage the whole process automatically?
thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Use `pip freeze` to create a list of installed packages and `pip download` to download them. Move them to your offline location and install them all with `pip install`:

```bash
$ pip freeze > requirements.txt
$ pip download -r ../requirements.txt -d packages
$ # move packages/* to offline host

offline_host$ pip install packages/*
```